# Create WPF SolidColorBrush in Non-UI-Thread leads to strange exception

Tags: wpf, multithreading, exception, datagrid, styles

I know that it's not allowed to create WPF UI elements such as a SolidColorBrush in a non-ui-thread.
I did it by accident and instead of WPF telling me that this is not allowed, I got a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in `MultipleCopiesCollection.get_item()`:

```
System.Windows.Controls.MultipleCopiesCollection.get_Item(Int32 index) System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.InternalItemAt(Int32 index) System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.GetItemAt(Int32 index) System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.GetItemAt(Int32 index) System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.VirtualizeChildren(List1 blockList, IItemContainerGenerator generator)
System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.GenerateAndMeasureChildrenForRealizedColumns(Size constraint)
System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellsPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)

[... a lot more FrameworkElement / Measure call stack]
```

I'm using the SolidColorBrush in a Style Setter of a DataGridCell in a DataGrid.

I expect WPF to tell me that I can't create the SolidColorBrush in the Non-UI-Thread.
Does anyone know why there is no proper exception for my error?

PS: It happened to me because some UI actions in Outlook / VSTO AddIns seem to be called from the outlook message loop and lead to the fact that `SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null`. In this case code after an `await` statement might run in a non-ui-thread.

Found out that between the thousands of exceptions one Exception was
`Error: Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject even by using Dispatcher`.
So I just had to look at the right exception...

Comment: SolidColorBrush is a DispatcherObject. A DispatcherObject can be instantiated everywhere, like any other type. Once created it is associated with the Dispatcher of the current thread. To access the DispatcherObject from any other thread requires to do it using the associated Dispatcher to avoid a cross-thread exception. If the object is a frozen Freezable, then the Dispatcher association is lifted (and the instance is unhooked from the dependency property system) and the instance can be referenced using any Dispatcher.

Comment: In other words, *creating* the object is not the problem, but which Dispatcher executes the referencing code. Your error probably occurred before any illegal reference. The exact cause is impossible to tell without reviewing the code.

Comment: Your updated error message is about *consuming* the DispatcherObject (SolidColorBrush) and not about *creating*  it. This should be clear. There will never be a cross-thread exception thrown on object creation (in contrast to your expectations: *"I expect WPF to tell me that I can't create the SolidColorBrush in the Non-UI-Thread"*). Cross-threading is always about consumption (references).

Answer (score 2):

It is a misconception that creating a `SolidColorBrush` (or any other `Freezable`) in a thread other than the UI thread is "*not allowed*".

It is allowed, you just have to make sure to call `Freeze()` before you use the object in the UI thread.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.freezable?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks):

> A class that derives from Freezable gains the following features:
>
> - Special states: a read-only (frozen) state and a writable state.
> - Thread safety: a frozen Freezable object can be shared across threads.
> - ...

Comment: Good point thanks for having this. Though it wasn't what I asked for ;)